# AWS Lambda function returning error : Lambda function could not be function using sls deploy with Node Js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless

Error:
**UPDATE_FAILED**: HelloLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "**Lambda function** shop-manager-admin-api-dev-hello could not be found" HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)

I tried changing the function name in handler.js from **module.exports.hello** to **module.exports.server** and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to resolve the issue.
Options:

1. When you run **sls deploy** from cmd, an **AWS CloudFormation Stack** is also created automatically along with an S3 bucket. So if you delete a Lambda function you must as well delete the cloud formation stack associated with the Lamba function.
2. Another option is to rename the function name in **serverless.yml** to a new one, so that a Lambda function with a different name will be created

Comment: If I may add, it's best to not do any manual changes to the resources deployed with Serverless Framework (`sls deploy` and so on). If you need to remove a function, remove it from serverless config and run `sls deploy` again.

Comment: Okay thanks. Let me try that as well